# javascript image change after 'x' amount of time

Tags: javascript, image, timer

How would I go about adding a timer to this js so images would change automatically after 'x' amount of time. As it stands the change is made via 'a href' with the 'rel' attribute, but that function with the 'rel' is still required.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#button a').click(function(){
        var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#myslide .cover').css({left:-1476*(parseInt(integer)-1)}).hide().fadeIn(); /*----- Width of div mystuff (here 160) ------ */
        $('#button a').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
            if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
                $(this).addClass('active')}
        });
    }); 
});
```

html:

```
<div id="myslide">
<div class="cover">

    <div class="mystuff">
        <img src="images/header_01.jpg" rel="1"></img>
        <img src="images/header_02.jpg" rel="1"></img>
        <img src="images/header_03.jpg" rel="1"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should consider using setInterval and and an array of images to change the source. This will force the image to loop continuously

```
var images = ['header_01.jpg','header_02.jpg','header_03.jpg'], 
    index = 0, // starting index
    maxImages = images.length - 1;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var curImage = images[index];
    index = (index == maxImages) ? 0 : ++index;
    // set your image using the curImageVar 
    $('div.mystuff img').attr('src','images/'+curImage);
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: I should note i'm new to js, and clueless as to how to incorporate this into the existing js.

Comment: Place this block of code within the document ready function. Fill the `images` array with the names of images you want to cycle through. You can remove all of the images in the `.mystuff` div except one. I've updated my code. It "should" work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTimeout function to call a predefined function to change your images like this:

```
var changeImage = function (){
<code>
};
var t = setTimeout(changeImage, <time in milliseconds>);
```

Make sure you are not calling `setTimeout(changeImage(), <time in milliseconds>);` (note the two parentheses)

This is to be avoided and you should try to use a function instead of a string to be evaluated as the first parameter to setTimeout().

Alternatively, you could use an anonymous function instead of creating changeImage.
Ex.

```
var t = setTimeout(function() { <code>}, <time in milliseconds>);
```

Comment: God kills a puppy ever time you pass a string to `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @Squeegy - If you're going to post, at least make it constructive criticism with some details. Everywhere I look online, there are quotes wrapped around the function name.

Comment: You do it the right way farther down, but passing a string to `setTimeout()` is considered a form of `eval()` and is to be avoided if at all possible.  I just wanted it to be clear to this buding JS programmer that passing a function object to `setTimeout()` is always better than a string to be evaluated.

Comment: Anonymous functions are part of what JS so powerful. :)

Comment: I should note i'm new to js, and clueless as to how to incorporate this into the existing js

Comment: @Crax - use the last line in my answer inside of your `$(document).ready(function() {` and where I wrote `<code>`, replace that with whatever you have in your javascript that changes the images. You might need to make an array of images + loop that loops through your images.