# Change image in HTML page every few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, image, timer

I want to change images every few seconds, this is my code:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript">

    function changeImage()
    {
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    img.src = images[x];
    x++;

    if(x >= images.length){
        x = 0;
    } 
   var timerid = setInterval(changeImage(), 1000);
}   }
var images = [], x = 0;
images[0] = "image1.jpg";
images[1] = "image2.jpg";
images[2] = "image3.jpg";

      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload = "changeImage()">
 <img id="img" src="startpicture.jpg">
   </body>
</html>
```

My problem is its stuck on the first picture!

I also wanted to try flipping through the pictures with previous and next buttons but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You don't have any function called `startTimer`.

Comment: With setInterval() you dont need setTimeout() and you don't need to re-set it after each tick.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086290/javascript-image-change-after-x-amount-of-time

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As I posted in the comment you don't need to use both `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`, moreover you have a syntax error too (the one extra `}`). Correct your code like this:

(edited to add two functions to force the next/previous image to be shown)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function startTimer() {
              setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
          }

          var images = [], x = -1;
          images[0] = "image1.jpg";
          images[1] = "image2.jpg";
          images[2] = "image3.jpg";
      </script>
   </head>

   <body onload = "startTimer()">
       <img id="img" src="startpicture.jpg"/>
       <button type="button" onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>
       <button type="button" onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: okey thank you it worked!!!!
but i was also wondering if i could add a net and previous to flip through images?? i have no idea how to do that one

Comment: Edited, just add two buttons where you trig the onclick even to call displayNextImage() and displayPreviousImage().

Comment: ugh! am still stuck on the same picture!
coule something be wrong with my browser??

Comment: It was an error in the source code (missing `function` keyword), fixed.

Answer (score 8):

below will change link and banner every 10 seconds

```
   <script>
        var links = ["http://www.abc.com","http://www.def.com","http://www.ghi.com"];
        var images = ["http://www.abc.com/1.gif","http://www.def.com/2.gif","http://www.ghi.com/3gif"];
        var i = 0;
        var renew = setInterval(function(){
            if(links.length == i){
                i = 0;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i]; 
            document.getElementById("bannerLink").href = links[i]; 
            i++;

        }
        },10000);
        </script>



<a id="bannerLink" href="http://www.abc.com" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" src="http://www.abc.com/1.gif" width="694" height="83" alt="some text">
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `setTimeout("changeImage()", 30000);` to `setInterval("changeImage()", 30000);` and remove `var timerid = setInterval(changeImage, 30000);`.

Answer (score 2):

As of current edited version of the post, you call `setInterval` at each change's end, **adding a new "changer" with each new iterration**. That means after first run, there's one of them ticking in memory, after 100 runs, 100 different changers change image 100 times every  second, completely destroying performance and producing confusing results.

You only need to "prime" `setInterval` once. Remove it from function and place it inside `onload` instead of direct function call.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the images at the beginning and change the css attributes to show every image.

```
var images = array();
for( url in your_urls_array ){
   var img = document.createElement( "img" );
   //here the image attributes ( width, height, position, etc )
   images.push( img );
}

function player( position )
{
  images[position-1].style.display = "none" //be careful working with the first position
  images[position].style.display = "block";
  //reset position if needed
  timer = setTimeOut( "player( position )", time );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best way to swap images with javascript with left vertical clickable thumbnails**

SCRIPT FILE:
    function swapImages() {

```
    window.onload = function () {
        var img = document.getElementById("img_wrap");
        var imgall = img.getElementsByTagName("img");
        var firstimg = imgall[0]; //first image
        for (var a = 0; a <= imgall.length; a++) {
            setInterval(function () {
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgall.length);
                firstimg.src = imgall[rand].src;
            }, 3000);



            imgall[1].onmouseover = function () {
                 //alert("what");
                clearInterval();
                firstimg.src = imgall[1].src;


            }
            imgall[2].onmouseover = function () {
                clearInterval();
                firstimg.src = imgall[2].src;
            }
            imgall[3].onmouseover = function () {
                clearInterval();
                firstimg.src = imgall[3].src;
            }
            imgall[4].onmouseover = function () {
                clearInterval();
                firstimg.src = imgall[4].src;
            }
            imgall[5].onmouseover = function () {
                clearInterval();
                firstimg.src = imgall[5].src;
            }
        }

    }


}
```