# javascript setInterval / onload

Tags: javascript

I'm referring to the accepted answer for [Change image in HTML page every few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975891/change-image-every-few-seconds). In this code, the very first timer event/image change occurs 6 secs after loading (then every 3 secs as expected). Could anyone explain to a beginner like me why this is so?
Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry for that, my fault. Let me try to explain what I'd like to do in the first place. The code given shows first startpicture.jpg and then cycles through image1.jpg to image3.jpg. I just want it to cycle through image1.jpg to image3.jpg without a seperate start picture (or all 4 pictures, including startpicture.jpg). Therefore is replaced startpicture.jpg with image1.jpg which made me get the wrong impression that the first image change occurred after 6 secs.

Maybe someone can help me how to change this code to cycling through the pictures without a designated start picture.

Comment: Where do you get the 6 seconds from? It is probably the time it needs to load the page until `startTimer` gets triggered.

Comment: Please consider create a http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate that.

Comment: As per the 1st comment, the javascript will 1st change the image 3 seconds after the body has loaded, How ong that takes it down to network latency,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your edit, you can simply remove the startpicture (or replace with image1), and initially call the displayNextImage function immediately, then start the interval:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function startTimer() {
              //call immediately
              displayNextImage();
              //then start interval
              setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
          }

          var images = [], x = -1;
          images[0] = "image1.jpg";
          images[1] = "image2.jpg";
          images[2] = "image3.jpg";
      </script>
   </head>

   <body onload = "startTimer()">
       <img id="img" src="image1.jpg">
       <button onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>
       <button onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be its time taken to load the images ,
you can load all the image first and then start changing,

```
var images= new Array();
for(var i=0;i<imagelocation.length;i++)  
{
images[i]=new Image();
images[i].onload=function(){ if(i=imagelocation.length){changeImage();}}
images[i].src=imagelocation[i]; //image location is array containg link
}
function changeImage()
{ 
 //what u had written earlier
}
```