# Replace image 1 with image 2 after 5 sec

Tags: javascript, image

I have found this script. but i want to display another image instead of the text "SOME TEXT".

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("div#outer").fadeOut("slow", function ()
            {
                $("div#outer img").remove();                
                $("div#outer").html($("div#text").text());
                $("div#outer").show();
            });
         }, 5000);
     });
```

```html
<div id="outer"><img src="http://existdissolve.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/microsoft-logo-64x64.png" alt="" /></div>
<div id="text" style="display:none">SOME TEXT</div>
```

Comment: Change the image `src` instead.

Comment: `$("div#outer").style("display","none");` instead of removing the image, just hide it.

and then `$("div#text").style("display","block");` where instead of text you put some `<img>` inside

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change image in HTML page every few seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975891/change-image-in-html-page-every-few-seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the image src or remove image and create a new one with some dynamic id or smth.

Here is a js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/s57qok3n/.

HTML:

```
<div id="outer"><img src="http://existdissolve.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/microsoft-logo-64x64.png" alt="" /></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("div#outer").fadeOut("slow", function ()
            {
                $("div#outer img").remove();                
                var img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); //Equivalent: var img = $(document.createElement('img'))
                img.attr('src', 'http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg');
                img.appendTo('div#outer');
                $("div#outer").show();
            });
         }, 5000);
     });
```

And if you want to change only the src attribute, here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("div#outer").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $("div#outer img").prop('src', 'http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg');
            $("div#outer").show();
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Working js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4faco2d9/

Comment: I've updated my answer with the change src solution. If this answer was suitable for you, you can point this as accepted answer. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> But i want to display another image instead of the text "SOME TEXT"

**If** you want to change the image *instead* of the action which changes text then  :

You can try this :

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("div#outer").fadeOut("slow", function ()
            {
                $("div#outer img").prop('src','the new img url');                    
            });
         }, 5000);
     });
```

Your question is not 100% clear.