# Change image in HTML page every few seconds using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a page where I need to have 3 images, one below another, and I need to change them every 10 seconds (for example: images 1-3 are displayed, after 10 seconds images 4-6 are displayed, after 10 seconds images 7-9 are displayed, ..., images 1-3 are displayed).

For now on, I have a code, which changes only the first from the 3 images. How could I make it so it just change all of the 3 images at once, after every 10 seconds?

Here's a javascript sample:

```
<script>
        var links = ["http://www.example.com","http://www.def.com","http://www.ghi.com"];
        var images = ["http://www.example.com/img1.png", "http://www.example.com/img2.png", 
              "http://www.example.com/img3.png", "http://www.example.com/img4.png",
              "http://www.example.com/img5.png", "http://www.example.com/img6.png"
             ];
        var i = 0;
        var renew = setInterval(function(){
            if(links.length == i){
                i = 0;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i]; 
            document.getElementById("bannerLink").href = links[i]; 
            i+=1;

        }
    },10000);
</script>
```

HTML code :

```
<a id="bannerLink" href="http://www.example.com" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" src="http://www.example.com/img1.png" width="694" height="83" alt="some text">
</a>
<a id="bannerLink" href="http://www.example.com" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" src="http://www.example.com/img2.png" width="694" height="83" alt="some text">
</a>
<a id="bannerLink" href="http://www.example.com" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" src="http://www.example.com/img3.png" width="694" height="83" alt="some text">
</a>
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------EDIT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Please, take a look at the code below. I need something like this:

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
    <script>
        var links = ["http://www.example.com","http://www.example.com","http://www.example.com"];
        var images = [  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Example_image_not_be_used_in_article_namespace.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Example_image.png",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/90/Contoh.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/P%C5%99%C3%ADklad.jpg"
             ];
        var i = 0;
        var renew = setInterval(function(){
            if(links.length == i){
                i = 0;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i]; 
            document.getElementById("bannerLink").href = links[i]; 
            i+=1;

        }
        },3000);
        </script>
</head>
<a id="bannerLink" href="http://www.example.com" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg"  alt="some text">
</a></br>
<a id="bannerLink" href="http://www.example.com" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png" alt="some text">
</a></br>
<a id="bannerLink" href="http://www.example.com" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Example_image_not_be_used_in_article_namespace.jpg" alt="some text">
</a></br>

</body>
```

With the above code, only the first image changes, the second and the third are the same all the time, but I need to change them too after very 10 seconds (I need to do the same thing as I did with image 1, with images 2 and 3).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change image in HTML page every few seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975891/change-image-in-html-page-every-few-seconds)

Comment: ID should be unique...

Comment: May be you are setting only one image (bannerImage)? As your above code implies?

Comment: As @Victoray mentioned you have to set unique Id like bannerImage1, bannerImage2,... etc. because javascript not uses multiple same ids at same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version has links as well. Try this [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/07m8039j/4/)

```
<a id='bannerLink1' href="#"><img src="" id='img1' ></a>
<a id='bannerLink2' href="#"><img src="" id='img2' ></a>
<a id='bannerLink3' href="#"><img src="" id='img3' ></a>

<script>
var images = ["http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG1&w=327&h=420", "http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG2&w=327&h=420", "http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG3&w=327&h=420",
              "http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG4&w=327&h=420", "http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG5&w=327&h=420","http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG6&w=327&h=420","http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG7&w=327&h=420"
             ];

var links = ["http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG1&w=327&h=420", "http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG2&w=327&h=420", "http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG3&w=327&h=420",
              "http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG4&w=327&h=420", "http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG5&w=327&h=420","http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG6&w=327&h=420","http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=85&bg=ef4135&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMG7&w=327&h=420"
             ];
var i = 0;
var renew = setInterval(function(){
        if(i==images.length) i=0;
        document.getElementById("img1").src = images[i]; 
        document.getElementById("bannerLink1").href=links[i];
        if(i+1==images.length) i=-1;
        document.getElementById("img2").src = images[i+1];
        document.getElementById("bannerLink2").href=links[i+1];
        if(i+2==images.length) i=-2;
        document.getElementById("img3").src = images[i+2];
        document.getElementById("bannerLink3").href=links[i+2];
        i+=3;


},1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it definitely does! Thanks! Just another question: how can I add links to images, so that by clicking on image it will redirect me to the page I want?

Comment: OK, I have added the links as well. Try it now. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have set 3 seconds interval and alert to display different image changes so please have a look, may be this will help you

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
    <script>
    var images = ["img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"];
    function changeImage()
    {
        var i = 0;
        var inter = setInterval(function(){
            if(i < images.length)
            {
                //document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i];
                alert(images[i]);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i = 0;
                //document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i];
                alert(images[i]);
                i++;
            }
        },3000);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="changeImage()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){
    functions here.
}, 10000);
```

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp