# Change image more than one time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I wrote this code so every time a button is clicked the background of a div will change 2 times:

```
$("#auto").click(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
             $('#screen').css('background-image','url(./img/2.jpg)');
                }, 400);
        setTimeout(function(){
             $('#screen').css('background-image','url(./img/3.jpg)');
                }, 800);
    });
```

But if we have many pictures, there should be a smarter way to do it without repeating thefunction. Can you guys help me?

I have an idea of putting the pictures inside a div, but the code I have only change one picture at a time. How can I display all those pictures, in an interval of 1s for picture?

```
<div class="slides">
        <div><img src="img/0.jpg" ></div>
        <div><img src="img/1.jpg" ></div>
        <div><img src="img/2.jpg" ></div>
        <div><img src="img/3.jpg" ></div>
        <div><img src="img/4.jpg" ></div>   
        <div><img src="img/5.jpg" ></div> 
</div>

var slider = $('.slides div');
    var intervalHandler = null;
    slider.hide();
    slider.eq(0).show();
    clickCount = 0;

$("#auto").click(function(){
          clearInterval(intervalHandler);
          intervalHandler = setInterval(function(){$(".SlNextBT").click();},1000);
         if(clickCount < slider.length)
               slider.eq(clickCount++).hide();
         if(clickCount == slider.length)
             clickCount = 0;
          slider.eq(clickCount).show();
     }) ;
```

Comment: You can checkout this answer . It is similar to your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/13976049/6396645

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easy to make this more generic and able to accommodate lots of pictures without hardcoding each one. Loop from 0 to the number of images, multiply the counter variable by how long you want each image to show in the `setTimeout` call and dynamically build the image url (since it is numeric).

```
function changeImage(index) {
   return function() {
      var currentImage = './img/'+(index+1)+'.jpg';
      $('#screen').css('background-image','url('+currentImage+')');
   }
}

$("#auto").click(function() {
    // let's say you have 5 pictures
    var numberOfPictures = 5;
    // 1 second
    var waitPeriod = 1000;

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPictures; i++) {
        setTimeout(changeImage(i), i * waitPeriod);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, but its only jumping  to the last img.

Comment: @FernandoSouza oops! You are totally correct, I carelessly forgot about binding and the problems with creating a function within a loop. The answer is updated to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi, tell me, what should I do if I want to play those pictures in the reverse order... I tryed var i = 0; i > numberOfPictures but it dint work.

Comment: Invert the loop. Start at numberOfPictures - 1, continue while 'i >= 0' and decrement i rather than increment

Comment: var numberOfPictures = -1;
     for (var i >= 0; i --) {
        setTimeout(x(i), i * waitPeriod);

  }

Comment: Yes you are, a for loop has 3 sections: initialization, continuation condition, and post process operation. Change to `for (var i = numberOfPictures - 1; i >= 0; i--) { setTimeout(x(i), i * waitPeriod); }`

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will review loops a litle bit.