# How To Automatically Change An HTML Image Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

NB: ***I've had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975891/change-image-in-html-page-every-few-seconds) for how to change the images on a timer, as oppose to using buttons, but it didn't cater to my code style.***

As I'm new to HTML and JS I still don't understand all the aspects and got a little confused on which part they were referring to in translation to how I wrote my code.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img id="image" src="blank_light.jpg" style="width:100px">
    <p></p>
    <button class="change-image">Change Lights</button>
    <script>
      var imageSources = ["red_light.jpg", "red_and_yellow_light.jpg", "yellow_light.jpg", "green_light.jpg"]
      var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("change-image")[0];
      var index = 0;

      buttons.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (index === imageSources.length) {
          index = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("image").src = imageSources[index];
        index++;
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to remove the buttons and have the images change on a *timed* basis instead. Ideally every 2 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the same link he posted in the question, it's not the same problem

Comment: @ACOMIT001 Like Mattia kindly said, it's a different problem as the link I posted has a different original format as me. There's no point writing a bunch of code if I don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use setInterval function to change image after every 2 sec

```
<img id="image" src="blank_light.jpg" style="width:100px">
<p></p>

<script>

var imageSources = ["red_light.jpg", "red_and_yellow_light.jpg", "yellow_light.jpg", "green_light.jpg"]

var index = 0;
setInterval (function(){
  if (index === imageSources.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("image").src = imageSources[index];
  index++;
} , 2000);

</script>
```

CodePen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNWMJK

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak Thanks a lot both of you. Am I correct in saying I can remove the <(/)button>

Comment: The image gets stuck on the first one, without changing at all? Any ideas. Please feel free to proofread the code, bearing in mind I initially copied and pasted your work to Notepad to see if it worked.

Comment: @freddie.bumder : not getting you. Is it working or not?

Comment: No. The image is staying as the blank traffic light. Not changing to any of the others.

Comment: Where do I do that? In the original question as an update?

Comment: @freddie.bumder : yes you can update your question below

Answer (score 0):

```
/CoffeeScript
$(document).ready ->
  imageSources = ["image1.jpg", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png", "image5.png"]
  index = 0
  setInterval ( ->
    if index == imageSources.length
      index = 0
    $('#image-test').attr('src', imageSources[index]);
    index++
    return
  ), 2000
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Elaborate what your snippet does and why it solves the problem.