# refresh multiple images using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have built a page that pulls in multiple images from various webcams that we use  the office to monitor road networks.

We want the images to update automatically every 30 seconds, ut my JavaScript isn't brilliant I'm afraid.

I know I can refresh the whole page easily, and I can refresh a single image just fine too. But multiple images from different URLs is proving more difficult.

The camera images are the only images on the page, if that's useful, and are displayed in HTML like such:

```
<figure class="fluid tiles">
<img src="cam/17002.php" alt="M" onerror="this.src = 'camoffline.png';" />
<figcaption class="textStyle">M20 00/1A J10-11<br /><small>Camera: 17002</small></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Please include the code you've tried (even if it's just refreshing a single image).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change image in HTML page every few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975891/change-image-in-html-page-every-few-seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// get all of the images from the page
const images = document.getElementsByTagName( 'img' );

// perform this function every 30,000 ms (30 sec)
const timer = setInterval( function(){
  // go through each image and reference a custom attribute
  // 'data-source' to preserve the original image's src
  for( var i=0, x=images.length; i<x; i++ ){
    // select each image, individually
    let image = images[i];
    let source = image.getAttribute( 'data-source' );
    // if 'data-source' does not exist, create it
    if( !source ){
      source = image.src;
      image.setAttribute( 'data-source', source );
      // give 'data-source' the original image path
    }
    // Add a timestamp to the image source to help mitigate 
    // browser caching
    image.src = source + '?t=' + Date.now();
  }
}, 30000 );
```

```css
img{ height: 150px; }
```

```html
<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo--week-old-cocker-spaniel-puppy-630877553.jpg">

<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo--week-old-cocker-spaniel-puppy-630877553.jpg">

<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo--week-old-cocker-spaniel-puppy-630877553.jpg">

<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo--week-old-cocker-spaniel-puppy-630877553.jpg">

<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo--week-old-cocker-spaniel-puppy-630877553.jpg">
```

Use .getElementsByTagName('img') to collect all the images that exist on your page.

Then, in an interval (setInterval: code that will continue to execute every ### miliseconds) create a for-loop that will iterate through the HTML collection captured with .getElementsByTagName()

One idea is to create a new attribute on each image on your page, 'data-source' (data- attributes can really be anything).  'data-source' will keep the original information for the path to the image file.

Then, using the value from the original image path, reassign that image path value to the image, but add in a timestamp as a query parameter.  This is to help the browser load a new image (browser's love caching content, where they can).  The browser sees image.jpeg?t=1234 and thinks it is a different image than image.jpeg?t=1233

Comment: `const`, `let` and `var`? O.o

Comment: lol -- old habits bleeding through an attempt to use the new :P

Comment: doug give an explanation .'

Comment: explanation added and beefed up comments in the code too :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to propose a slightly modified solution that uses a `<canvas>`.  This will paint all of your sources in a fixed width container and, if they are offline, draw the "Offline" text where the source should have been.

Click the checkbox to test the offline functionality.

```js
const sources = [
  "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg",
  "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg"
];

function getSources(offline = false) {
  return !offline ?
    sources.map(src => `${src}?cb=${Date.now()}`) :
    sources.map(() => "");
}

function loadImage(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(img));
    img.addEventListener("error", () => reject(`Problem loading ${src}`));
    img.src = src;
  })
}

const offlineCheckbox = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0],
  canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0],
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const {
  width,
  height
} = canvas;

function refresh() {
  console.log("Updating");
  getSources(offlineCheckbox.checked).forEach((source, idx, arr) => {
    const w = width / arr.length,
      dx = w * idx,
      dWidth = w * (idx + 1);

    loadImage(source)
      .then(img => {
        ctx.clearRect(dx, 0, dWidth, height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, dx, 0, dWidth, height);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        ctx.clearRect(dx, 0, dWidth, height);
        ctx.strokeText("Offline", dx, height * 0.5, dWidth);
      })
  });

  setTimeout(() => refresh(), 3 * 1000);
}

refresh();
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Pretend to be offline</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a **[timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)** to reset the `src` of the image every 30 seconds:

```js
var img = document.querySelector("img.cam");
setInterval(function(){
  // I'm appending # and a date to ensure we don't use a cached version of the file
  img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random#" + new Date() ;
}, 2000); // number is in milliseconds
```

```css
img  { width: 100px; }
```

```html
<figure class="fluid tiles">
<img class="cam" src="cam/17002.php" alt="M" onerror="this.src='camoffline.png';" />
<figcaption class="textStyle">M20 00/1A J10-11<br /><small>Camera: 17002</small></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Did you test your "solution"? Your solution only works for one image, so you would have to add one "solution" for every webcam. And a changed hash value won't force the browser to get a new version of the image.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I did test my solution and yes, a changed file name (to one that hasn't been downloaded before) does force the browser to ignore the cache. It's just the SO Code Snippet environment that is preventing it from showing

Comment: @Andreas And, this solution could easily be scaled to handle any amount of images with a simple loop.

Comment: _"a changed file name (to one that hasn't been downloaded before)"_ -  Yes, but the browser ignores anything after `#` in regards of caching. Just open the network tab and check the requests. The `src` will only be changed once and there won't be an updated version of the image (from the webcam)

Comment: @Andreas You are getting too hung up on something that is unrelated to the question or answer. With the random image source that I'm using (simply for demo purposes), this is what you have to do to make it work.

Comment: Erm... TO wants to automatically reload all images every x seconds. Your solution doesn't fulfill this requirement.