# Problems Cycling through Images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, asp.net-core

I am currently having a problem with my function not correctly cycling through images. The first image I have in the html code will show, but the code attempts to switch to a second image but instead just shows the blank white background. All images lie in the same directory folder. I have checked and made sure all file names and extensions match the their true names, attempted to find any syntax errors that might be causing this not to run but to no avail. could it be the fact that I am attempting to create an array and populate it at the same time, but doing so incorrectly?

**Here is the answer I based my code off of:** [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975891/change-image-in-html-page-every-few-seconds)

Here's my current relevant code:

**JS:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayNextImage() {
            var i = (i === imgArray.length - 1) ? 0 : i + 1;
            document.getElementById("image").src = imageArr[i];
        }

        function displayPreviousImage() {
            var i = (i <= 0) ? imgArray.length - 1 : i - 1;
            document.getElementById("image").src = imageArr[i];
        }

        function startTimer() {
            setInterval(displayNextImage, 2000);
        }

        var imageArr = ["~/Images/Carrying Food In.jpg", "~/Images/Food Pantry.jpg", "~/Images/Fresh Produce.jpg", "~/Images/Handing Out Food.jpg", "~/Images/Man Pushing Wheelbarrow.jpg", "~/Images/Woman Leading Class.jpg"], i = -1

    </script>
```

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<body onload="startTimer()">
    <img id="image" src="~/Images/Food Pantry.jpg" style="width: auto;" />
    <p></p>
</body>
```

*Edit: Changed one method to previous (had two of the same method names) - problem still persists*

Answer (score 0):

That's because of misspelled reference to your array and because on every function run you redeclare iterator variable `var i`. This code should work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        var imageArr = ["~/Images/Carrying Food In.jpg", "~/Images/Food Pantry.jpg", "~/Images/Fresh Produce.jpg", "~/Images/Handing Out Food.jpg", "~/Images/Man Pushing Wheelbarrow.jpg", "~/Images/Woman Leading Class.jpg"], i = -1
        var i;

        function displayNextImage() {
            i = (i <= 0) ? imageArr.length - 1 : i - 1;
            document.getElementById("image").src = imageArr[i];

        }

        function startTimer() {
            setInterval(displayNextImage, 2000);
        }


    </script>
```

Comment: hm... so I found and corrected all those things and it still didnt work so figured it was something small that I missed. Then pasted your code directly in and still received the same issue of when switching to the second picture receiving the blank white background

Comment: FYI: I also changed the method name above. I am supposed to have a method for previous and next and accidentally named both showNextImage().